# Как запретить растягивание textarea через css?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, как я могу запретить растягивание textarea через css?

Пример:

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь `resize: none` для `textarea`:

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Нет репутации даже лайк посавить

Comment: @TheBeast поднял на 5)))

Answer (score 1):

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Нет репутации даже лайк посавить

Comment: выберите лучшим - это же можно -  поднял на 5

Comment: показывает что надо ждать какое-то время

Comment: сами решите - удачи

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте resize: none;

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Нет репутации даже лайк посавить